# How to access a java code level variable in jenkins in post build actions - slack notifications

Tags: java, jenkins

There is a java String variable in my code, say

`String jenkinsVariable = "hello World"`

After running this code in jenkins, I am sending few data in Custom Message under post build actions -> Slack Notification(external plugin).

Like wise, I need to get the above mentioned variable value also in Custom Message

Approaches tried:

I made the above mentioned variable as System variable using

`System.setProperty("jenkinsVariableToAccessInPostAction", jenkinsVariable)`

In the post build actions -> Slack Notification(external plugin) -> Custom Message, tried to access it using

`${ENV,jenkinsVariableToAccessInPostAction}`

`${ENV.jenkinsVariableToAccessInPostAction}`

But both the above mentioned approach are not working.
I am getting ${ENV,jenkinsVariableToAccessInPostAction} and ${ENV.jenkinsVariableToAccessInPostAction} itself getting printed in my slack message

Comment: Could you please add more context, e.g. what type of Jenkins job you're running and where do you run the specified code?

Comment: Its a testng selenium script, Ideally my whole point to get the variable in java code to be accessed in jenkins post actions -> slack notifications

Comment: So you're basically trying to share a variable between different processes running in different JVMs, which is... Well, kind of almost impossible, to be short. Before we continue, please edit your question and specify your higher-level goal, e.g. what information do you want to include in that notification, because the answer will most likely depend on that.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are trying to share data between the java application and the executing Jenkins pipeline, this is not possible directly via setting an environment variable as it affects only the current running session and not the environment object stored by the Jenkins file - which you are trying to access.

The easiest way to overcome this is to write the relevant data you want, in this case the parameters and their value, to a file and then read the file via the pipeline and extract the relevant data.

For example, in your java application create a file called `params.properties`, and write to it your needed parameters in a [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) file format:

```
var1=value1
var2=value2
var3=value3
```

Then in your post build just read this file using the [readProperties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) step to read the file ,and you will get the needed values in the returned dictionary.

```grrovy
post {
   always {
       def loadedParams = readProperties file: 'params.properties' // load the parameters from your parameters file
       println("Value for loaded var1 is ${loadedParams['var1']}") // use the values loaded from the file
   }
}
```

You can of course use different formats for your parameter files like Yaml or Json, and then use the corelated pipeline steps to read them.

Comment: so this post script needs to go inside 
Build Environment -> Inject environment variables to the build process

Comment: In a declarative pipeline this script is the post build section. In scripted pipeline this can be replaced with a step that injects the environment variables to the build.

Comment: So ideally writing this post script under the Inject environment variables to the build process , will fetch the variables only during the post build actions, right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. My previous comment was not correct, The groovy script above is for **decelerative** pipelines, in **scripted** pipelines you can use the same without `post` directive, and in **freestyle jobs** you have a built in step that can inject variables - it can be used in the build section or in the post build section, and only after it is called would the variables be available in the build.